# Twilio Copilot send message response has segment count as zero

Tags: twilio, sms

When a message is sent using Twilio copilot (Twilio Node.js library), it seems like the numSegment (num_segment) count is always zero.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Sorry this was a slow response. I'm not sure what you're asking here though. The code you show there just lists the messaging services that you have. What are you trying to achieve and what is the code you are using for it?

Comment: Hey @philnash, the question is why numSegment field in the response is always zero, when a message is send using a messaging service?

Comment: That's right, but I would like to see the code you're using so that I can see what you're doing and either correct it or reproduce the issue myself.

Comment: any answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is expected behavior, as there won't be a price back, from this link, it's seems best to wait about 3 seconds or have a call back to make a get request

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/45